# Not able to turn on wifi after reboot

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, broadcom

I have Acer Aspire 5560G laptop. I've been using it with wifi networks for a while. Anyway, once I left it in suspended mode, then switched it off by long-pressing power button and after booting again WiFi stopped working. 
I still see red cross on wifi tray icon and it says, that no connections are available.
I tried Fn+F3 combination (wifi switch) hundreds of times, but it doesn't work. My laptop doesnt have a hardware switch as far as I can tell, at least I haven't switched it off before it stopped working.
I tried to enable-disable device from control panel, reboot with clean services list, restoring to last restore point, but nothing helped.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you

Comment: I have a laptop that does this at times.  I connected it to the internal temperature, using a laptop cooler, prevents this from happening for the most part.

Comment: Try going into the Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`) and click the `Scan for hardware changes` button on the toolbar.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but laptop is cold right now and I still not am not able to connect. 'Scan for hardware changes' didn't help either

Comment: Does the Network Interface Card (NIC) appear in device manager? Does a wired connection work properly?

Comment: I don't know what happened, but when I booted to check that, wifi just connected. Thank everyone for your suggestions, but it looks like Ramhound was correct - that's heating issue. Ramhound, if you create an answer from your comment, I will make that as a correct one.