# Switch on wifi programmatically

Tags: wireless-networking

My wifi switch on my laptop (running Windows 7 Ultimate) is not working, but my wifi receiver still is intact. Below, in the system tray, there's an icon which represents wifi connections, and it says *'no connections available'*. Seems logical. When I click on *'Troubleshoot'*, it says, *"Use the switch on the front or side of the computer, or function keys if available, to enable wireless capability on this computer."*.

Note that the wireless network connection is listed in both the device manager and the list of network devices.

[image: Wireless network connection is still intact]

But is there a way to switch on wifi programmatically?

PS: I found a similar problem in [Not able to turn on wifi after reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/625452/not-able-to-turn-on-wifi-after-reboot), but no answers yet.

Comment: Are you able to use Fn + F4 to switch it on? Not sure if you can use this when there is a built in button.

Comment: @MatthewWilliams It doesn't work. As far as I know, my laptop has no function keys to enable wireless networking. In my case, `Fn`+`F4` would turn the computer on standby.

Comment: You can press Win+X which opens the Mobility Center (Vista/7 only), and then you should be able to turn the Wi-Fi on from there. In Windows 8 and later, Win+X opens the quick link menu which can be used, among other things, to launch the Mobility Center.

Comment: @and31415 The 'enable' button in the 'wireless network' section is greyed out.

Comment: @MCEmperor What operating system are you using? Is the wireless card listed in the Device Manager?

Comment: @and31415 I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate. And yes, the wireless card is listed in the device manager, the OS does not report any problems with it, except that my wireless networking device is not switched on. I also expanded the question with this information.

Comment: From your description, it seems like the switch in question forcibly disables the wireless network card. What computer model are you using? If you run a Linux Live distro, do you get the same issue?

Comment: @razumny It is an Acer Aspire 7730G-734G64MN, see http://www.ferra.ru/images/219/219477.jpg. The wifi switch is the second of the five buttons on the left. I have not tested to run a Linux Live distro.

Answer (score 0):

The switch is a physical switch. When it is off, there is no power to the WiFi card. Therefore, it can not be turned on via software.  You didn't say there was physical damage to the switch, so maybe it's a driver issue. Below is a simple procedure you can try. If it's a corrupted driver, this usually takes care of it.

1. Go back into the `Device Manager`
2. Highlight the device, right click and choose `uninstall`.
3. Now highlight the top of the tree, the computer name
4. Right click. Choose `Scan for hardware changes` to allow the
   computer to reinstall the hardware.

It may require a reboot.

Comment: Your answer seems ... conflicted. The switch in question is either a hard on/off switch, or it triggers a software response. If it is the first, your solution would not - could not possibly - work.

Moreover, the button in question is most certainly NOT a hard power on/off switch; as Acer does not use those.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like either a driver issue, or an issue with the wifi card itself. The easiest way to test it, is to test it using a Linux Live Distro. If the issue persists, then you may be fairly confident that the hardware is at fault.